# How to do null or empty check in drools - mvel dialect?

Tags: drools, rules, business-rules, mvel

When the configList is null, the AND logic should not proceed further, but I am getting this error - **"array index out of bounds"**.

Below is the rule :

```
rule "testRule"
   when
       config : Config( configList != null && !configList.empty && configList[0].attribute != null )
   then
       // logic
end
```

Comment: Before answering your question, are you aware that checking for null is not the same as checking for "emptiness"?

Comment: Hi, I do know the difference but I posted the wrong code, please check the edited code as it is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way Drools executes the conditions of the rules, short-circuit logical operators are not guaranteed. In some cases they work, but in some other cases they don't.

As a workaround, you might split the single pattern you have into two:

```
rule "testRule"
when
  config : Config( $configList: configList != null, configList.empty == false)
  Attribute() from $configList.get(0)
then
  // logic
end
```

I'm assuming that `$configList` is a list of `Attribute` objects.

Hope it helps,